# Counting the emails in an excel file(python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a excel file that includes many emails and some of them are written more than once. I need to count have many times those emails were repeated. how do I do that by using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all emails are in a "clean" format (not a free text field with misspellings, extra spaces, etc.).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['add1','val1'],
    ['add2','val2'],
    ['add3','val3'],
    ['add1','val4']
    ],columns=['Address','Value'])


df.groupby('Address').count()

         Value
Address       
add1         2
add2         1
add3         1
```

The DataFrame needs to have columns besides what you are grouping on.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['add1'],['add2'],['add3'],['add1']],columns=['Address'])

df.groupby('Address').count()

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [add1, add2, add3]
```

Things you can do with groupby:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html

How to use groupby:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby